# how to select query in specfic time mysql

Tags: mysql

i have some problem on select query between 2 column times.
i have 2 column 'timefrom', 'timeto'
example

```
Select * 
from table 
where  timefrom <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H') 
AND    timeto  >   DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H')
```

like our `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H')` is 19 hour

```
Select * from table where 18<=19 AND 07>19
```

in this query i select data between 18 hour to next day 07 hour 
but our time is 19 hour its will be true but above its return false becasue its 07>19 show false . 
please tell me how to solve it .

second we not use 'ÓR' in my query we want to only use AND
please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H')  
BETWEEN timefrom  AND timeto;
```

but if 'timeto' is date of next day, you must make like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H%d/%m/%Y')  
BETWEEN timefrom  AND timeto;
```

and you must save data into 'timefrom' and 'timeto' columns like this :'**%H%d/%m/%Y**'